# Help me solve this limit...

Tags: limits

I have to find $\lambda$ so that the function:

[image: Function]

has a limit at $x0=2$.
I've tried to write the limit of 2x + $\lambda$ as $x \to -\infty$ equals to 2. But I have no idea what to do with $x^2+1$. Please help me solve this...

Comment: You can express $x\to-\infty$ with `x \to -\infty`

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand what $\lambda$ has to do with this. Around $2$, the function is just equal to $x^2+1$. And why are you taking limits as $x\to-\infty$ ?

Comment: The function is 2x+$\lambda$ when $x<0$, so $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not the continuity to ensure ?

Comment: @A6Tech I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I don't understand the task too, but OK, I guess I'll skip it then.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I suspect that it is about a limit in $0$ here. Function $f$ has a limit at $0$ if $\lim_{x\downarrow0}f\left(x\right)$
and $\lim_{x\uparrow0}f\left(x\right)$ both exist and are equal.
It is clear that $\lim_{x\downarrow0}f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)=1$.
You have $\lim_{x\uparrow0}f\left(x\right)=\lambda$. So $f$ has
a limit at $0$ if $\lambda=1$.
Only in this context I can understand the exercise.